# Very slow USB 3 connection

Tags: usb, usb-3

Is it the case that if I plug in one USB 2 or USB 1 stick into the hub then the entire USB network of the hub will become the lowest speed? Because I get very slow results even though two connected drives are USB 3. I'm going to try and disconnect everything else. The connection is usb c to a targus docking station and then usb 3.

[image]

Comment: Could you give the model ID of the mainboard/laptop, and the targus dock? The issue source is the USB 3.0 HUB chip workflow (which is integrated with USB 2.0 hub chip for compatibility), and the large number of files (if target on your picture is not SSD).

Comment: Could you please draw a diagram of what is connected to what, and what is the transfer direction? Also, please run any disk benchmark over  the Targus dock, individually with your USB3 drives in question.